# Showing association records index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

**Edit #1**

`course_modules_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @course_modules = CourseModule.all
  @courses = Course.all
  @course_exercises = CourseExercise.all
end
```

`course_modules/index.html.erb`

```
<section class="pt-4 px-8">
  <section class="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
    <h3 class="font-normal text-grey-dark mb-4 py-2">
      Course Modules
    </h3>
    <%= render 'layouts/dashboard/account' %>
  </section>
</section>

<section class="accordion-toggle">
  <section class="px-8">
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <section class="w-full py-4">
      <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter">
          <section class="flex justify-between p-6 p-4">
            <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
              <section class="font-bold text-base">
                <%= course.title %>
              </section>
            </section>

            <i class="flex items-center fal fa-angle-up ml-2"></i>
          </section>
        </section>
      </section>

      <section class="accordion-items hidden">
        <% @course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
          <section class="w-full">
            <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter border-b">
              <section class="flex justify-between px-6 p-4">
                <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
                  <section class="font-bold text-base">
                    <%= course_module.title %>
                  </section>
                </section>

                <section class="modules">
                  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_module_path(course_module), class: "inline-block text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>

            <section class="accordion-exercises">
              <% @course_exercises.each do |course_exercise| %>
                <section class="w-full">
                  <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter border-b">
                    <section class="flex justify-between px-6 p-4">
                      <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
                        <section class="font-bold text-base pl-4">
                          - <%= course_exercise.title %>
                        </section>
                      </section>

                      <section class="exercises">
                        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_exercise_path(course_exercise), class: "inline-block text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                      </section>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </section>
              <% end %>
            </section>
          </section>
        <% end %>
      </section>
    <% end %>
  </section>
</section>
```

**Original Question**

I have three models, course, course_modules and course_exercises.

On the index view of the course modules, I want to show the course, modules and exercises like so

[image]

However, it doesn't seem to take into account the id for example

[image]

Test Module belongs to course #1 and Module #1 belongs to course #2 also test exercise belongs to Module #1

[image]

How do I have it do it which id to use and where to go.

I.e. I only want the modules to belong to the course listed and the same can be said for the exercises belonging to the module.

Comment: I’m not getting where you stuck, maybe you can add the code of your actual view?

Comment: @iGian See Edit #1 for code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to figure out the problem you are getting, this should be a simplified view:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <h3><%= course.title %></h3>
  <% course.course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
    <h4><%= course_module.title %></h4>
    <% course_module.course_exercises.each do |exercise| %>
      <p><%= exercise.title %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Rendering as:

```html
<h3>Course #1</h3>
<h4>module #1-1</h4>
<p>#1-1-1</p>
<p>#1-1-2</p>
<p>#1-1-3</p>
<h4>module #1-2</h4>
<p>#1-2-1</p>
<p>#1-2-2</p>
<p>#1-2-3</p>
<p>#1-2-4</p>
<h3>Course #2</h3>
<h4>module #2-1</h4>
<p>#2-1-1</p>
<p>#2-1-2</p>
<p>#2-1-3</p>
<h4>module #2-2</h4>
<p>#2-2-1</p>
<p>#2-2-2</p>
<p>#2-2-3</p>
```

This supposing your models are

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :course_modules
end

class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :course_exercises
end

class CourseExercise < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_module
end
```

Comment: Please see Edit #1 for the code on how it's currently setup

Comment: Check if the models I added are compliant, in case, paste the view code and check if it works as expected. In case you can apply your styles.

Comment: This is what I get the models are the same as you have above https://gyazo.com/3e411649923eb1cced2bf47771e74a4b the controller index is like so https://gyazo.com/3556fd59e6f3f3d51c66368692d4909a the database looks like this https://gyazo.com/45e49bedab494de4f69c29654c6364e9

Comment: Rails standard is to use singular names for foreign_keys: you have `course_modules_id` instead of `course_module_id` in `course_exercises` table. One possible option is to run a migration to rename that column: `rename_column :course_exercises, :course_modules_id, :course_module_id`

Comment: Alternatively, instead of changing the column name, you can add the custom foreign key to `CourseModule`, like so: `has_many :course_exercises, foreign_key: :course_modules_id`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is pretty simple. You iterate over every course exercise for every course module, and iterate over every course module for every course. Where you should just iterate over the course exercises that belong to a specific course module, and iterate over the course modules that belong to a specific course.

This means you controller should look like this:

```
def index
  # the includes solves the N+1 query problem
  @courses = Course.all.includes(course_modules: :course_exercises)
end
```

And your view should look like this:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <% # code for courses %>

  <% # instead of @course_modules.each %>
  <% course.course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
    <% # code for course modules %>

    <% # instead of @course_exercises.each %>
    <% course_module.course_exercises.each do |course_exercise| %>
      <% # code for course exercises %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### References:

- The `#course_modules` and `#course_exercises` helper methods are created by specifying an [`has_many`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) association (see link for generated methods).
- [`#includes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) to solve the N+1 query issue.

Comment: Also, why are you indexing courses in your course modules controller? This seems more at home in the courses controller.